# Finding all non trivial congruence relations on (N, +)

Tags: abstract-algebra, congruence-relations

I want to find all [congruence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation) on ($\mathbb{N}, +$). Clearly, we have $\bigtriangledown_\mathbb{N} = \mathbb{N} $ x $ \mathbb{N} $ and $\bigtriangleup_\mathbb{N}  = \{(x,x)| x \in \mathbb{N}\}$. How do I determine non-trivial ones? How can I prove that these, then, are all of them?

Comment: What is your definition of "congruence relation"?

Comment: Does your definition of $\mathbb{N}$ include $0$?

Comment: @GregMartin [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $0\in\Bbb N$, we can say that $\Bbb N$ is the *free monoid* generated by one element. (On the other hand, if you assume $0\notin\Bbb N$, then it's the *free semigroup* on one element.)

Its quotients are precisely all the monoids [semigroups] generated by one element.

Let $\def\th{\,\vartheta\,} \th$ be a congruence relation on $(\Bbb N,+)$.

1. Take the least $n>0$ such that $n\th 0$. If such $n$ exists, we will have $1+1+\dots+1=0$ in the quotient, so that's going to be a cyclic group of order $n$.
2. Otherwise - Take the least $n$ that is congruent to somebody else than itself, and take the least such somebody else, $m=n+d$. 
   Then, in the quotient, we will have $n=n+d=n+2d=n+3d=\dots$, i.e. it's a cycle of $d$ elements over a tail of the first $n$ elements.

Can you explicitly write up the congruences?

> See also [monogenic semigroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenic_semigroup).

Comment: Yep, $0 \in \mathbb{N}$. So I guess I should arrive at sth. like this: 
let $n, d \in \mathbb{N}$. Then we have that $m$ ~ $l$ $\Leftrightarrow$ 1.case) $m = l$ or 2.case) $\exists e < d \exists i,j \in \mathbb{N} \colon n+di + e = m \wedge n + dj + e = l$ ??

Comment: Yes, this formulation seems right.. In case 2., with the $n,d,m$ as introduced there, we will have $n+di\,\vartheta\,n$ in the quotient, so $n+di+e \,\vartheta\, n+e$ if $e<d$. Same applies to the other one, $n+dj+e\,\vartheta\,n+e$.

Comment: @Berci I know you wrote this answer over a year ago but I have a similar problem right know. Do you really mean $=$  and not $\theta$ in the expressions $1+1+1+\ldots +1 =0$ and  $n=n+d=\ldots$  ?

Comment: What's $\vartheta$ in a structure $A$ is strict equality in $A/\vartheta$. That's what quotient structure is. And that's why *cosets* make a good representation: if $a\, \vartheta\, b$ in $A$, then their equivalence classes are equal: $[a] _\vartheta =[b]_\vartheta$.

Comment: ah, thank you very much - so the expressions left and right of the equality represent the equivalence classes.